# Set Alerts on Indicators (Interactive Brokers Api)

Tags: interactive-brokers, tws

Is it possible to access real time computed values of Indicators , inorder to set **Alerts** on them  (eg. ***Stochastic D-K crossover***)?

The available Tick types [(link)](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/tick_types.html) provided in Tws-api doesn't mention any way to access them.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you want to subscribe to market data and calculate the indicators yourself.
It is not possible to interact with indicators at all via the api.